# pymongo inserting many documents in a mongo db that might contain duplicates

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a mongo db with a collection called "ActiveTracking", with a custom key that is "dates". Periodically, I get new documents in bulk that might have duplicate "dates, and new "dates".

my dictionary of records looks like this:

```
dicto = [{'_id': Timestamp('2004-02-25 00:00:00'),
  'low': 2.809999942779541,
  'volume': 12800,
  'open': 2.9000000953674316,
  'high': 2.9000000953674316,
  'close': 2.819999933242798,
  'adjclose': 1.5342552661895752,
  'dividends': 0.0},
 {'_id': Timestamp('2004-02-26 00:00:00'),
  'low': 2.819999933242798,
  'volume': 59500,
  'open': 2.8499999046325684,
  'high': 2.9000000953674316,
  'close': 2.890000104904175,
  'adjclose': 1.572339653968811,
  'dividends': 0.0},]
```

For example, the first record is in the db, the second is not. If I do:

```
collection = db["STOCK"]
collection.insert_many(dicto, ordered=False)
```

returns

```
BulkWriteError: batch op errors occurred
```

My collection has thousands of records, and the "bulk" I receive might contain 100s (as opposed to the 2 I show in the example). Is there anyway to write to the db ONLY the unique ids, in bulk?

**Update**
The following code might work, but I am trying to avoid iterating over the dictionary to be inserted (to check for duplicates), before inserting. I prefer a solution that does not iterate over a long list, to discriminate what to insert, since it could be time consuming.

```
to_be_inserted = []
for d in dicto:
    x = collection.find_one(d)
    if type(x) != dict:
        to_be_inserted.append(d)
collection.insert_many(to_be_inserted)
```

Answer (score 1):

The following pseudocode should work. Check for the existence of the record using `find_one` and if the record is not present add it to a `to_be_inserted` list. Insert
all in a batch at the end.

As `_id` is always indexed by default you will get very fast performance on your `find_one`.

If you know some of the properties of your timestamps you may be able to optimise further 
by keeping track of your oldest and newest timestamp and seeing if incoming timestamps are 
within or outside that range.

```
to_be_inserted = []
for d in candidate_records:

    if col.find_one(d["_id"]):
        continue
    else:
        to_be_inserted.append(d)

if len(d) > 0:
    col.insert_many(to_be_inserted)
    to_be_inserted = []
```

Comment: Thank you. The code I added above works, but I am trying to avoid iterations over list/dictionary to be inserted (to check for duplicates), since that can be slow (I am working with financial data, and bad ticks / gaps in data are not uncommon, but speed correcting/inserting data is important). There has to be a way to do it in one pass in mongodb; however, I have not found it yet.

Answer (score 0):

This is called an [unordered bulk write](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/examples/bulk.html#unordered-bulk-write-operations).